# Iterate over this JSON object and get it's values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an JSON array (object), and I want to navigate throuhgt it and get it's values. But I'm getting :"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

This is the ajax function that generate the JSON:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "<?php echo $html->url(array("controller" => "porders", "action" => "getBudgetProduct")); ?>",
  data: "product_id="+product_id+"&cantidad="+cantidad,
  dataType:"text json",
  success: function(producto){
    console.log(producto);
    addCost(producto, cantidad);

  },
  error: function() {
    console.log("Error en el AJAX");
  }
});
```

This is the array:

```
[
    {
        "Motion": {
            "id": "1801",
            "code": "31042014",
            "code2": "33207",
            "name": "CEBOLLAS X KILO",
            "composers": "0",
            "buy_price": "7400",
            "composition_cost": "0.00000000000000000000",
            "quantity": "7.5"
        }
    },
    {
        "Motion": {
            "id": "1912",
            "code": "31061009",
            "code2": "3134108",
            "name": "LECHE ENTERA EN SACHET X LT",
            "composers": "0",
            "buy_price": "3100",
            "composition_cost": "0.00000000000000000000",
            "quantity": "6.0"
        }
    },
    {
        "Motion": {
            "id": "1718",
            "code": "31034001",
            "code2": "31401",
            "name": "HUEVOS X UNIDAD",
            "composers": "0",
            "buy_price": "433.333333",
            "composition_cost": "0.00000000000000000000",
            "quantity": "50"
        }
    },
    {
        "Motion": {
            "id": "300001091",
            "code": "31053003",
            "code2": "35305",
            "name": "HARINA DE MAIZ X KGR",
            "composers": "0",
            "buy_price": "5000",
            "composition_cost": "0.00000000000000000000",
            "quantity": "4.500"
        }
    },
    {
        "Motion": {
            "id": "1748",
            "code": "31062016",
            "code2": "34202",
            "name": "QUESO PARAGUAY X KL",
            "composers": "0",
            "buy_price": "25000",
            "composition_cost": "0.00000000000000000000",
            "quantity": "4.500"
        }
    },
    {
        "Motion": {
            "id": "1775",
            "code": "31031005",
            "code2": "31101",
            "name": "ACEITE  A GRANEL X LT",
            "composers": "0",
            "buy_price": "7299.6",
            "composition_cost": "0.00000000000000000000",
            "quantity": "4.500"
        }
    },
    {
        "Motion": {
            "id": "1752",
            "code": "31035047",
            "code2": "31501",
            "name": "SAL FINA X KL",
            "composers": "0",
            "buy_price": "2037.98",
            "composition_cost": "0.00000000000000000000",
            "quantity": "0.225"
        }
    },
    {
        "Motion": {
            "id": "300001800",
            "code": "210402001",
            "code2": "84231",
            "name": "SOPA PARAGUAYA X KILO",
            "composers": "7",
            "buy_price": "0",
            "composition_cost": "10778.50661836734693877551020",
            "quantity": "7.5"
        }
    }
]
```

I have an html view, and I want to show the values of the array in a table. I'm doing it like this. (The addCost() function code):

```
function addCost(producto, cantidad)
{
    var html = '';
                html += '<h2>';
                html += '<?php  __("Costo de Producción");?>';
                html += '</h2>';
                html += '<h3>';
                html += '<?php  __("Lista de Semiterminados");?>';
                html += '</h3>';
                html += '<table id="items" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:500px;">'
                html += '<tr>';
                html +=     '<th><?php __("Codigo"); ?></th>';
                html +=     '<th><?php __("Codigo Secundario"); ?></th>';
                html +=     '<th><?php __("Producto"); ?></th>';
                html +=     '<th><?php __("Cantidad"); ?></th>';
                html += '</tr>';
                for (var i = 0; i < producto.length; i++) {
                    if (producto[i]["Motion"]["composers"] > 0) 
                    {
                        html += '<tr>';
                        html +=     '<td class="code">';
                        html +=         '<input type="hidden" value="" class="id">';
                        html +=         producto[i]["Motion"]["code"];
                        html +=         '&nbsp;';
                        html +=     '</td>';
                        html +=     '<td class="code2">';
                        html +=         producto[i]["Motion"]["code2"];
                        html +=         '&nbsp;';
                        html +=     '</td>';
                        html +=     '<td class="name">';
                        html +=         producto[i]["Motion"]["name"];
                        html +=         '&nbsp;';
                        html +=     '</td>';
                        html +=     '<td class="quantity">';
                        html +=         producto[i]["Motion"]["quantity"];
                        html +=         '&nbsp;';
                        html +=     '</td>';
                        html += '</tr>';    
                    };
                };
                html += '</table>';
);
```

This is the error that show the debugger:

[image: Debugger error]

The first console.log it's the console.log() of the returned json called producto

Cal you help me please. Thanks

Comment: show your javascript code!

Comment: As the debugger tells you, the problem is in the javascript file "budget" at line 1582. What object is "addCost" being called from? Could it be null at that point?

Comment: Is the code you provided from the addCost function? Where does `producto` come from?

Comment: What is `producto`? i'm betting it isn't an array. (the error indicates that it is in fact undefined)

Comment: yes sorry, i will update that, this is the code from the addCost function

Comment: You need to go up one or two more levels. What calls the function? Whatever is calling it is calling it with an undefined value.

Comment: What does the `20` mean?

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. Open your network tab and inspect the request. Is anything returned from it?

Comment: I updated the code, I'm calling the addCost function as a success response of an ajax

Comment: works fine if you're calling it like this http://jsfiddle.net/Looh5wkL/2/

Comment: @juanpscotto What does the `20` mean in the console

Comment: the 20 its a console.log of the variable "cantidad". Please can you return my points back (=. I have updated the code. Look at it please

Comment: @juanpscotto What points?

Comment: @PraveenKumar OP's rep is taking a hit on this question.

Comment: @khalid13 I understand. Not sure why he asked me. `:(`

Comment: Praven Kumar nothing is just to know if the value is ok. Kebin B, the json its returned from the ajax success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took both Javascript and your html its working properly here at Jsfiddle. [Link to working code](https://jsfiddle.net/vrrhsazz/)

So i think there is something else i guess some variable is undefined.

```
var producto=[
    {
        "Motion": {
            "id": "1801",
            "code": "31042014",
            "code2": "33207",
            "name": "CEBOLLAS X KILO",
            "composers": "0",
            "buy_price": "7400",
            "composition_cost": "0.00000000000000000000",
            "quantity": "7.5"
        }
    },
    {
        "Motion": {
            "id": "1912",
            "code": "31061009",
            "code2": "3134108",
            "name": "LECHE ENTERA EN SACHET X LT",
            "composers": "0",
            "buy_price": "3100",
            "composition_cost": "0.00000000000000000000",
            "quantity": "6.0"
        }
    },
    {
        "Motion": {
            "id": "1718",
            "code": "31034001",
            "code2": "31401",
            "name": "HUEVOS X UNIDAD",
            "composers": "0",
            "buy_price": "433.333333",
            "composition_cost": "0.00000000000000000000",
            "quantity": "50"
        }
    },
    {
        "Motion": {
            "id": "300001091",
            "code": "31053003",
            "code2": "35305",
            "name": "HARINA DE MAIZ X KGR",
            "composers": "0",
            "buy_price": "5000",
            "composition_cost": "0.00000000000000000000",
            "quantity": "4.500"
        }
    },
    {
        "Motion": {
            "id": "1748",
            "code": "31062016",
            "code2": "34202",
            "name": "QUESO PARAGUAY X KL",
            "composers": "0",
            "buy_price": "25000",
            "composition_cost": "0.00000000000000000000",
            "quantity": "4.500"
        }
    },
    {
        "Motion": {
            "id": "1775",
            "code": "31031005",
            "code2": "31101",
            "name": "ACEITE  A GRANEL X LT",
            "composers": "0",
            "buy_price": "7299.6",
            "composition_cost": "0.00000000000000000000",
            "quantity": "4.500"
        }
    },
    {
        "Motion": {
            "id": "1752",
            "code": "31035047",
            "code2": "31501",
            "name": "SAL FINA X KL",
            "composers": "0",
            "buy_price": "2037.98",
            "composition_cost": "0.00000000000000000000",
            "quantity": "0.225"
        }
    },
    {
        "Motion": {
            "id": "300001800",
            "code": "210402001",
            "code2": "84231",
            "name": "SOPA PARAGUAYA X KILO",
            "composers": "7",
            "buy_price": "0",
            "composition_cost": "10778.50661836734693877551020",
            "quantity": "7.5"
        }
    }
];

var html = '';
            html += '<h2>';
            html += '<?php  __("Costo de Producción");?>';
            html += '</h2>';
            html += '<h3>';
            html += '<?php  __("Lista de Semiterminados");?>';
            html += '</h3>';
            html += '<table id="items" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:500px;">'
            html += '<tr>';
            html +=     '<th><?php __("Codigo"); ?></th>';
            html +=     '<th><?php __("Codigo Secundario"); ?></th>';
            html +=     '<th><?php __("Producto"); ?></th>';
            html +=     '<th><?php __("Cantidad"); ?></th>';
            html += '</tr>';
            for (var i = 0; i < producto.length; i++) {
                if (producto[i]["Motion"]["composers"] > 0) 
                {
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html +=     '<td class="code">';
                    html +=         '<input type="hidden" value="" class="id">';
                    html +=         producto[i]["Motion"]["code"];
                    html +=         '&nbsp;';
                    html +=     '</td>';
                    html +=     '<td class="code2">';
                    html +=         producto[i]["Motion"]["code2"];
                    html +=         '&nbsp;';
                    html +=     '</td>';
                    html +=     '<td class="name">';
                    html +=         producto[i]["Motion"]["name"];
                    html +=         '&nbsp;';
                    html +=     '</td>';
                    html +=     '<td class="quantity">';
                    html +=         producto[i]["Motion"]["quantity"];
                    html +=         '&nbsp;';
                    html +=     '</td>';
                    html += '</tr>';    
                };
            };
            html += '</table>';
alert(html);
```

Comment: This is better suited to a comment - it's not really an answer.

Comment: What do you supposed the problem is?

Comment: can I use this syntax:  producto[i].Motion.quantity instead of this  producto[i]["Motion"]["quantity"] what's the difference?

Comment: I was declaring a undefined variable at the bottom of the function

Comment: I made the code work !! and it is suppose to give him insight... i would assume that his problem was not at length...